how to import sql tables data into multiple excel sheets?
I want to import Multiple Sql tables data into multiple sheets of single Microsoft excel Workbook.I am trying to import 3 different sql tables data into multiple sheets of single excel workbook. my first Sql table is name, my second sql table is email and my third Sql table is address. it should be imported in three different sheets of Microsoft excel with tab name.my code is not working and not creating Excel sheet with data.It is giving error
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
enter code here



    Public Sub Main()
    Dim currentdatetime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    Dim LogFolder As String = "D:\"
    Dim Excel_OLE_Connection As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim Excel_OLE_Command As OleDbCommand = Nothing
    Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection = Nothing

    Try
        Dim TableList As String = "name,email,address"
        Dim TableArray As String() = New String() {""}
        TableArray = TableList.Split(","c)
        Dim TableName As String = ""
        Dim DestfileName As String = "D:\"

        If File.Exists(DestfileName & ".XLSX") Then
            File.Delete(DestfileName & ".XLSX")
        End If

        Dim connectionString As String = "server= .\SQLEXPRESS; database = testdatabase; integrated security=true"
        Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand
        Dim connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & DestfileName & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"""

        For i As Integer = 0 To TableArray.Length - 1
            TableName = TableArray(i)
            Dim CreateTableQuery As String = "Create Table [" & TableName & "] ("
            Dim columnList As String = ""
            Dim Columns As String = ""
            sqlCon = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            sqlCon.Open()
            sqlCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" & TableName & "'", sqlCon)

            Using rdr As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
                Dim j As Integer = 0

                While rdr.Read()
                    Dim myString = rdr.GetString(0)

                    If j = 0 Then
                        columnList = "[" & myString & "] Text,"
                        Columns = "[" & myString & "],"
                    Else
                        columnList = columnList & " [" & myString & "] Text,"
                        Columns = Columns & " [" & myString & "],"
                    End If

                    j += 1
                End While

                columnList = columnList.Remove(columnList.Length - 1)
                Columns = Columns.Remove(Columns.Length - 1)
            End Using

            CreateTableQuery = CreateTableQuery & columnList & ")"
            Excel_OLE_Connection = New OleDbConnection()
            Excel_OLE_Command = New OleDbCommand()
            Excel_OLE_Connection.ConnectionString = connstring
            Excel_OLE_Connection.Open()
            Excel_OLE_Command.Connection = Excel_OLE_Connection
            Excel_OLE_Command.CommandText = CreateTableQuery
            Excel_OLE_Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & TableName & "", sqlCon)
            Dim insert_query As String = "Insert into [" & TableName & "] ( " & Columns & " ) VALUES("

            Using rdr As SqlDataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

                While rdr.Read()
                    Dim myString As String = ""
                    Dim insert_query2 As String = insert_query

                    For b = 0 To rdr.FieldCount - 1
                        myString = rdr(b).ToString()
                        myString = convertQuotes(myString)
                        insert_query2 = insert_query2 & "'" & myString & "',"
                    Next

                    insert_query2 = insert_query2.Remove(insert_query2.Length - 1)
                    insert_query2 = insert_query2 & ")"
                    Excel_OLE_Command.CommandText = insert_query2
                    Excel_OLE_Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End While
            End Using
        Next

        Excel_OLE_Connection.Close()
        sqlCon.Close()
    Catch exception As Exception

        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(LogFolder & "\" & "ErrorLog_" & currentdatetime & ".log")
            sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString())
        End Using
    End Try

End Sub

Public Shared Function convertQuotes(ByVal str As String) As String
    Return str.Replace("'", "''")
End Function


Which line does the error happen on? Are there any spaces in the string in DestfileName?
